# Is there any way to position a div by pixel like it is absolute positioned but have it take up space?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've constructed an slds path element with several steps. Under the current step I want some sub text information, but there may not always be subtext info for each step.

I achieved this by making an absolute positioned div with my information inside it, then determined the current step position:

```
get subtextStyle(){
    let subtextStyleStr = 'position: absolute; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: flex-start;';

    const pathItemElements = this.template.querySelectorAll('li.slds-path__item');

    for(let i = 0; i < pathItemElements.length; i++){

        if(pathItemElements[i].dataset.stepStatus === 'In Progress'){
            let offsetTop = pathItemElements[i].offsetTop + pathItemElements[i].offsetHeight;
            let offsetLeft = pathItemElements[i].offsetLeft;
            const width = pathItemElements[i].offsetWidth;

            subtextStyleStr += ' top: ' + offsetTop + 'px; left: ' + offsetLeft + 'px; width: ' + width + 'px;';
        }
    }

    return subtextStyleStr;
}
```

then doing `<div style={subtextStyle}>my subtext stuff</div>`

This almost gives me what I want, the subtext is placed right below the current path item and the text won't extend beyond the current path items width. The issue, is that it is absolute positioned, so it doesn't take up space, so won't extend a parent card container and may hide behind other things on the lightning page right below the bar.

Is there some positioning that can allow me to place something at a specific location, but also take up space to make sure it pushes everything below it down so it is always visible?

Essentially what I am after and what I have so far:

[image]

I just need that text to take up space so it never gets hidden.

Comment: Do you want it to be stationary even when scrolling down?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do position in a specific location AND have it affect the flow of the document. I'd suggest using `text-align: right` or using Flexbox to have the *`other text`* go on the right, and have vertical padding to add that space below **`some other text`**.